# Mi PWA no recibe notificaciones push de firebase levantadas con php

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-messaging, pwa

Tengo en el index.php

```
<!--- Notificaciones FIREBASE -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "....", //No lo publico intensionalmente
        authDomain: "smicam-web.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "smicam-web",
        storageBucket: "smicam-web.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "...",  //No lo publico intensionalmente
        appId: "....",  //No lo publico intensionalmente
        measurementId: "G-2CLZNCDH8E",
      messagingURL: '/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      
      // Obtiene la instancia de messaging
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    
        // Solicita permisos de notificación y obtén el token
        messaging.requestPermission()
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Permiso de notificación otorgado');
            return messaging.getToken();
          })
          .then((token) => {
           // Guardo el token obtenido en una base de datos con esta api
            var url = '/api/grabarToken.php?usuario=<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>&token=' + token;
            fetch(url);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error al solicitar permisos o al obtener el token:', error);
          });
          
          
          // Manejo de mensajes en primer plano
          messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
            console.log('Notificación recibida en primer plano:', payload);
        
            // Puedes mostrar la notificación directamente en tu aplicación
            const notification = new Notification(payload.notification.title, {
              body: payload.notification.body+'addefc',
              icon: payload.notification.icon,
            });
        
          });
          
        
    </script>
<!-- FIN FIREBASE-->
```

Por otro lado en regist_serviceWorker.js (entre otras cosas)

```
// Notificaciones Firebase
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
        .then(registration => {
            console.log('Service Worker firebase registrado con éxito:', registration);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error al registrar el Service Worker firebase :', error);
        });
```

y por ultimo el archvo firebase-messaging-sw.js con este contenido

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...", // Oculto intensionalmente
    authDomain: "smicam-web.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "smicam-web",
    storageBucket: "smicam-web.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "...",  // Oculto intensionalmente
    appId: "...",  // Oculto intensionalmente
    measurementId: "G-2CLZNCDH8E",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Recibida notificación en el Service Worker:', payload);
  titulo = payload.notification.title+'aaaaa2_';
  mensaje = payload.notification.body+'aaaaa2';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: mensaje,
  };
  self.registration.showNotification(titulo, notificationOptions);
});
```

Para levantar la notificacion push utilizo:

```
$mandar=array(
    'data'=>array(
        'notification'=>array(
            'title'=>$titulo,
            'body'=>$mensaje
            )
        ),
    'to'=>$token
    );
    
$header=array('Authorization: key='.$server,'Content-Type: application/json');
$mandar=json_encode($mandar);

$sh =curl_init();
curl_setopt($sh,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($sh,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($sh,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($sh,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($sh,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$mandar);

$result=curl_exec($sh);

echo $result;

curl_close($sh);
```

y en consola puedo ver el resultado que es:
{"multicast_id":4774063262220242074,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"3c00cd5e-35f1-42f2-9c25-d4e8f5bb1cf5"}]}

Pero no lo recibe la pwa, ni en una notebook ni en un celular,... que puede ser?
Adicionalmente procure desde la consola de firebase, entrar en la parte de campañas y hacer como que iniciaba una campaña. Alli permite mandar una notificacion de prueba a un token. Lo hice y esa notificación SI la recibí